# Child row datatables - row data value undefined

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I have a datatable with child rows populated by the following function:

```
$('#myDataTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            console.log(table.row(this).data());
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);

            if (row.child.isShown())
            {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }
            else {
                // Open this row
                row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }
        });
```

The format function:

```
function format(d) {
            // `d` is the original data object for the row
            return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
                '<tr>'+
                '<td><strong>BLABLA1</td>' +
                '<td align="center">'+
                    d.BLABLA1 +
                '</td>'+

                '<td><strong>BLABLA2</td>' +
                '<td align="center">'+
                    d.BLABLA2+
                '</td>'+
            '</tr>' +
            '</table>';
        }
```

However, when I display the page, and I expand the child rows, the values of the columns are "undefined"...

The rows in the datatable are populated from a model (Using MVC 4) as follows:

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr>

                <td align="center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BLABLA3)
                </td>
    .....</tr>}
    </tbody>
```

I think I am missing the method to get the row.data() loaded into the formatting function.... What is the correct way of doing so? I already checked all the documentations and they all use what I tried....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to select the index of the object/array returned by .data() for every row, the following code worked for me.....(replace KNOWN_INDEX  by integer index of the child row...)

```
<tr>'+
                '<td><strong>BLABLA1</td>' +
                '<td align="center">'+
                    d[KNOWN_INDEX]+
                '</td>'+
.
.
.
'</tr>'+
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's strange the page https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html explain that we have to write :

```
'<td>'+d.myrow+'</td>'+
```

But if i do this, row's value is "undefined", so i have to write :

```
'<td>'+d["myrow"]+'</td>'+
```

And it's works !